# How to override table layout using Global CSS in a multi-table environment?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

My pages uses a series of tables many of which use the following CSS to add a counter along the left side.

```
table.sortable tbody tr::before {
    content: counter(sortabletablescope);
    counter-increment: sortabletablescope;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

But some tables I have don't need that column. How can I override the global CSS for tables not needing the counter?

Comment: Use a class? `<table class="sortable with-counter">` & `table.sortable.with-counter tbody tr::before { … }`.

Comment: Can you modify the HTML?

Comment: You would need to identify it in the html somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If modifying the HTML is an option:

Use the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:not()) CSS pseudo-class.

> The :not() CSS pseudo-class represents elements that do not match a
>   list of selectors. Since it prevents specific items from being
>   selected, it is known as the negation pseudo-class.

This requires using a class in the elements that you want to target.

Notice that this however will give an unexpected result because the missing `::before` pseudo-element in these table rows will cause inconsistency:

```css
table {
  counter-reset: sortabletablescope;
}

table.sortable tbody tr:not(.different)::before {
  content: counter(sortabletablescope);
  counter-increment: sortabletablescope;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<table class="sortable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="different">
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>March</td>
      <td>$50</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

To solve this, use an empty pseudo-element like so:

```css
table {
  counter-reset: sortabletablescope;
}

table.sortable tbody tr:not(.different)::before {
  content: counter(sortabletablescope);
  counter-increment: sortabletablescope;
  display: table-cell;
}

table.sortable tbody tr.different::before {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<table class="sortable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="different">
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>March</td>
      <td>$50</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

If the list needs to have a descending order, the only constraint is that you must know the total number of rows that will be displayed.

Create a CSS counter scope with the total number of rows plus one; it is zero-based.

```
  counter-reset: <identifier> <totalNumberOfRows + 1>;
```

```css
table {
  counter-reset: sortabletablescope 3;
}

table.sortable tbody tr:not(.different)::before {
  content: counter(sortabletablescope);
  /* Substract 1 for each row. */
  counter-increment: sortabletablescope -1;
  display: table-cell;
}

table.sortable tbody tr.different::before {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<table class="sortable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="different">
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>March</td>
      <td>$50</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Any idea how I might make the numbers go in depending order? My table is sorted by last in on top, I'd like to see number 1 be at the bottom and add a number for each new row.

Comment: @KeithDKaiser Hi Keith! Yes, you must know the total number of rows that will be displayed though, I edited the answer, you can take a look there.

Comment: Beautiful, exactly what I did. The tables are generated by PHP/MYSql so it was easy to get the total number and then do exactly what you suggest.